# Searching for in an XML file for a specific product id

Tags: php, xpath

I ran into a problem that i've been trying to solve with no luck.

Im trying to search an XML-file for a specific product id. Following is a snippet from the XML-file.

```
products xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="xxxxxx">
<product articleNo="13000">
    <name>Fire Brigade Frame HB</name>
    <category id="6">Backbacks and bags</category>
    <languages>
        <lang id="1">
            <standardProperties>
                <property name="webHeaders">Stabil aluminiumram.  Passar otympliga bördor.  Kraftigt höftbälte.</property>
                <property name="webText">Aluminiumram med bärsystem utan säck. För tillfällen när stora otympliga bördor ska flyttas med muskelkraft. Kraftigt höftbälte och remmar för att fästa med. </property>
            </standardProperties>
            <extendedProperties>
                <property name="Webbing">Polypropylene, aluminium frame</property>
                <property name="Djup">32 cm</property>
                <property name="Höjd">80 cm</property>
                <property name="Bredd">36 cm</property>
                <property name="Total vikt">1900 g</property>
                <property name="Yttertält">1900 g</property>
            </extendedProperties>
        </lang>
```

as you can see in the XML-file there's a /products and a /product which includes an ID, this is the ID i want to search for.

I've been trying with the following code, But It only gives me an error.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("xxx.xml");
$results = $xml->xpath('/products[product articleNo=13000]');
print_r($results);
```

error message:

```
Warning: SimpleXMLElement::xpath() [simplexmlelement.xpath]: xmlXPathEval: evaluation failed in /xxx.php on line 85
```

line 85 is where the code is placed.

All the best,
Marten

Answer (score 1):

```
/products/product[@articleNo=13000]
```

Comment: as a bit of an explanation of the above the / generally means the next element and the @ generally means an attribute of an element. but if you were to do /products/product/@articleNo that would return the article numbers for each product